# adding static library in xcode 4.2 project

Tags: xcode

I am getting following  error while building my project after adding static library in xcode 4.2

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: Did this error happen after you linked your project with the library or after you tried to add a header from the library into one of your source files?

Comment: Also, are you dding just the .a library file or are you adding the xcodeproj for the library to your xcodeproj?

Answer (score 0):

You may beed to add some other linker flags to the build settings of your target. Check out the Build Settings in your target.
[image]

Usually this fixes the linking problem with static libraries.