# XCode 4.2 and Using a Static Library Causing Problems

Tags: xcode

Like many others here SO, I am having issues using libraries in my XCode workspace.  The idea is I have my main project (`MyApp`) and two libraries (`lib1` and `lib2`) which were added to the workspace after the code was finalized.

For background, `lib1` is dependent on lib2, since there are some protocols that need to be implemented in order to make use of `lib2`.  `MyApp` is dependent on both.  I have tried following the Apple guides, which implies what I would like to is simple.  After that, I have followed pretty much every post here on SO that has come up in my searches (2 days worth of Googling), plus many other blogs and posts that claim to have solutions, many of which are XCode 3 specific.

Yet, my project does not build.  I am using Xcode 4.2 on OS 10.6 (upgrading to Lion is not an option).  Is there a simple tutorial to follow on how to create a library project, and use this library in an application.

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065336/620197) while writing this question (where the question had the same error I had), which I will look into, but I have reached the point of copying source files over just to get a demo working.

UPDATE:

Here is list of issues that have come up.  I will add more when they arise:

- `**directory not found for option '-L/Users/myhomedir/iphoneprojects/MyApp/../BLProfile/build/Release-iphoneos'**`

Comment: You didn't explain what error you get or what is not working.

Comment: @sch I will try post some errors, but with attempt at a solution, new errors come up.  But the question still stands without the errors, is there a simple set of instructions somewhere on how to create a library project and actually use it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is how to create a static library and a project that use it.

**Step 1:** Create a workspace: **File > New > Workspace**. This is not mandatory but it helps organize the projects.

**Step 2:** Create a static library project: **File > New > Project > Framework and Library > Cocoa Touch Static Library**. Lets call it **MyLib**.

**Step 3:** Create an Application Project: **File > New > Project > Application> Empty Application**, or any other application template. Lets call this project **MyApp**. If you placed the projects in different folders, you may have to use a different path.

Now you have the following Projects in the workspace.

[image: Project structure]

**Step 4:** Configure the app so that it finds the `.h` files of the library. To do that, add the parent folder **"../"** and check the **recursive** checkbox.

[image: Header Search Path]

**Step 5:** Link the app to the library.

[image]

Comment: The step where I set the header search path, I do not get the pop up that has the recursive option.

Comment: @MikeD - Double click on the **User Header Search Paths** line, or simply hit the enter key and write **../\*\***.

Comment: Now I have a more concrete error.  Since I have a library that depends on another library, I get an error where lib1 can not find a header file in lib2.

Comment: Do the same steps 4 and 5 to lib1 so that you can use lib2 inside of it.

Comment: This adds the library from the products directory, right? If I'm not mistaken, that's built for iphoneos, so this wont run on the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Main Project where you would like to add static library.
2. Save as workspace.
3. Add library's project package. No need to check copy while adding project package.
4. Update Xcode preferences location to Custom-Relative to Workspace. Products as 'Build/Products' and Intermediates as Build/Intermediates
5. In your Main project -> target -> build settings, Add Header and Library Search Path as $(BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR)
6. Build Library Project. So a new library will be created in mentioned build path.
7. Remove existing library from Build Phases and move to trash. Open Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries and add newly created library from build directory.