# xcode target dependencies between two projects

Tags: xcode, dependencies, nsbundle

I have a problem with setting dependencies in XCode 4 between separate projects. Currently, I have two projects in the same workspace. The *first* project have a *Framework* amongst it's products. I would like to use this framework in the *second* project, as a dependency for **Bundle** target.

First project build successfully. However, the second one claims that it cannot access headers from the framework, although it exists in there. I added the framework to *Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries* section of my target, but this does not help. I was looking for an answer, but all I found were suggestions to add library on the *Summary* page. Unfortunately, in opposite to *Application* targets, *Bundle* target does not have this pane. Is there any other place where should I add the framework?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode 4.2 and Using a Static Library Causing Problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726000/xcode-4-2-and-using-a-static-library-causing-problems)

Answer (score 2):

This answer describes the current procedure for adding a library dependency, including headers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726445/382938