# How to add project inside another project in ios

Tags: ios, static-libraries

May I know how can I use the whole application project in my another project in Xcode.

By simply dragging the whole project in my new project its not working ,showing the file is not imported , if I want to use any class of the existing project in my new project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible dupli : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370518/xcode-4-2-how-include-one-project-into-another-one

Answer (score 0):

Here are some great step-by-step instructions on how to add static library dependencies in more recent versions of Xcode.

Use these links .

[Xcode 4.2 how include one project into another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370518/xcode-4-2-how-include-one-project-into-another-one)

[XCode 4.2 and Using a Static Library Causing Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726000/xcode-4-2-and-using-a-static-library-causing-problems?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create workspace (File -> New -> Workspace. In workspace you can add as much projects as you want.