# Adding a project as a dependency in Xcode

Tags: xcode, dependencies, dependency-management

I've been trying to add an Xcode project (a static library) as a dependency to another project (a framework). I've read about this issue, but I can't find what I'm looking for. Specifically, what I find is a way to add the static library **binary** as a dependency (in target dependencies), but this is not what I want. Instead, I have two projects configured in the same workspace. Similar to this:

[image]

([Image credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726000/xcode-4-2-and-using-a-static-library-causing-problems?answertab=votes#tab-top))

What I want is for the `MyLib` project to **build** when `MyApp` builds, if needed. I'm not just interested in adding the static library for linking. Is this possible?

Edit: I'm currently exploring the possibility of doing this using a `Run Script`. If possible I'd like a better alternative, though