# How to access one project classes from other project While using multiple project with one Workspace

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, mobility

I am using two different project within one workspace. I have one base(Say Unity-iPhone) project and i drag and drop another iOS project (Say InnerApp). Each file and folder are visible in base project as attached screenshot. I have also added the dependency in build phase of base project, and set the other linker flag and header search path.

Now I want to access the InnerApp classes and storyboard file in base project.

[image: One project inside another project]

[image: Added dependency in base project]

[image: Set Other linker flag]

[image: Set header search path]

Now My problem is that, I want to launch the Inner App Main.storyboard into base project. But InnerApp classes are not accessible into base project.

Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting header not found issue while importing header files

Answer (score 0):

You can follow some great step-by-step instructions on how to add static library dependencies while using multiple projects.

Use below urls -

[Include one project into another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370518/xcode-4-2-how-include-one-project-into-another-one)

[Include static libraries into another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726000/xcode-4-2-and-using-a-static-library-causing-problems?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I have imported the one project into another project, Now my issue is that how can i access the InnerApp classes into base project. I added the both project into one workspace and able to build successfully, but issue is access one project classes to another project.